# The provider for keystore type 'IBMCMSKS' is not available

Tags: http, webserver

I am using IBM HTTP Server 9.0 , when i try to create a .kdb file, it is throwing error as " The provider for keystore type 'IBMCMSKS' is not available. ",

Note :- 'CMS' Key Store is not present in the ikeyman.bat file

Please help me how to add this key store in the ikeyman

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In IHS 8.5.5 this option has helped me: `-DADD_CMS_SERVICE_PROVIDER_ENABLED=true`

E.g.

```
 /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/java/jre/bin/ikeycmd -DADD_CMS_SERVICE_PROVIDER_ENABLED=true -cert -getdefault  -db XXX.kdb  -stashed
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while using IHS 8.5.5.15, and resolved by adding providers in java.security
security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.pkcs11impl.provider.IBMPKCS11Impl
security.provider.2=com.ibm.security.cmskeystore.CMSProvider

Ensure you have correct numbering of rest of providers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gskcapicmd` if it is available.  This won't work with JKS files though.  Or upgrade to 9.0.0.3 which fixes the issue.